# c++ converting unknown struct to string

Tags: c++, parsing, struct, void

i have a question. Is it possible to get all data types and the variable names from a struct? For example:

```
void func(void *p){
std::cout <<  "p->type_1" << ... << "p->type_x" << std::endl;
std::cout <<  "p->name_1" << ... << "p->name_x";}

typedef struct{
int a;
char b;
float c;
}test;

test a;
func(&a); 
//There should come something like 
"int char float"
"a b c"
```

Comment: No, c++ doesn't support reflection (yet).

Comment: At best you've got typeid: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid
But that can only extract the type, if you know the name.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, an [X-Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) can help but this is really really ugly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST \
    X(int a;) \
    X(char b;) \
    X(float c;)

typedef struct {
#define X(x) x
    TEST
#undef X
} test;

void print()
{
#define X(x) puts(#x);
    TEST
#undef X
}

int main(void)
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
int a;
char b;
float c;
```

Comment: Love X Macros. So useful, though a bit too clever in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you would need support for introspection in C++, and runtime type information. Some languages have this built in, but C++ does not (well, not enough for this purpose).

Depending on your needs, you could build information about your `struct`'s data types and pass a pointer to that information along with that struct pointer into your function. Useful tools for this might be the `typeid` operator, the `offsetof` macro, the `typeof` macro, and the C preprocessor with its stringify operator (`#`).

With those you should be able to build an array that contains a field's name, something that identifies what primitive type it has, and at what offset in the `void*` it can be found. You might have some more work if you need to also support fields of other `struct` types (basically you'd need to embed their fields into that structure, or reference it.

That said, there might be better, easier ways to do this depending on what you need this output for and how much control you have over your code and the `struct`s you want to print.

For example, most debuggers can print `struct`s using platform-specific debug metadata, so you might not need this approach if you're just trying to improve your debug experience (this information is often in separate files and contains many other things, so isn't suitable for use outside debugging).

Alternately, if you can modify the classes (in C++ classes and `struct`s are the same thing) you get, you could give them all a common base class and a `print()` method. Then each `struct` would know how to print itself, and you could just call that.

There might be other solutions if you can use, but it depends on why you need this and who controls the classes you're trying to print and why. E.g. Object graph serialization tools etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrive from  struct. 
From the variable , u can get:

```
int a= 5;
cout << "a has type: " << typeid(a).name()
```

Output : int

Answer (score -3):

If it's a struct, all fields are public so nothing prevent you to do std::cout << typeid(p->a) << typeid(p->b) << std::endl; std::cout << p->a << p->b << endl

Comment: The point is that we do not know what type of `struct` gets to `func`. It might not contain fields `a` and `b`

Comment: "*If it's a struct, all fields are public...*" No, not in C++. In this particular example all members are public, but that is unrelated to `struct` being used. The same could be done with `class`.

Comment: sasha is right, the function i want to write doesnt know the type of the struct. I know that i could cast the void pointer to the struct i need, but thats not what i want.

Comment: @juanchopanza "If it's a struct, field default visibility is public *" Better ?
Then no, there's no reflexitivity in C++. You could transform your function in a template function and it would do basically the same but would not compile if you attempt to read or write a field that doesn't exist in the typename you would use.